# Sync Google Calendar with sharepoint Calendar

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-services

How to synchronize Google calender with SharePoint 2010 calender ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess most options have already been mentioned, but here's my view on this.

Google has an API which you can use to query an online calendar for appointments. If you do so, you can use the SharePoint object model to insert the appointments into a SharePoint calendar. Of course, for syncing you would need to store the original ID of the Google appointment. By the way, I suppose you need a one way sync Google -> SharePoint, if not; things become far more complicated.

The code you'd need to write would
a) Query Google's API and get the appointments
b) Then get the appointments from your SharePoint calendar 
c) Compare the two and process the changes in the SharePoint calendar

I would personally create a SharePoint timer job to do this, which you can configure in central administration to run once an hour (or any other frequence you'd might like).

There's no out of the box way to do it, and most tools out there have already been mentioned. So the question than is: do you have the option of custom development, or not?

Comment: Yes i want custom development

Comment: Then you've got every bit of info you need I think?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what your looking for:

http://www.rssbus.com/kb/articles/webpart-googlecalsync.rst

also been asked here :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382897/sharepoint-calendar-sync-with-google-calendar

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This very much possible as there are various ways to implement this.

Please check this [Link](http://kmlsp.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/sync-calendar-between-sharepoint-google-outlook/) to find out how to achieve this using a tool called Google Calender Sync.

Check this [Link](http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/sharepoint-to-google-calendar-synchronization/) to see how to do it using Google API and .NET

Finally a DIY webpart [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2010/01/13/10-diy-sharepoint-web-parts-10.aspx). But please note this all these need to embed your user id and password, which is not encrypted or completely secure.

Also I would not recommend this for Production sites for obvious reasons.

Comment: i already done this but its not working

Comment: Which approach did you try and what is exactly not working for you?

Comment: i tried with RSSBus but there is error like Could not find the library 'RSSBus.GoogleOps'.

Comment: i also tried SharePoint To Google Calendar Synchronization but i dont understand where to writ code and where to deploy

Comment: To be precise, RSSBuss and Camelot.Net connector are paid products which you need to buy to use for commercial purpose.

Comment: Could you please try the Google Calender Sync which can sync your google calender to outlook calender which you can later sync to SharePoint. Also can you please check this [link](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/mashpoint/archive/2009/01/26/how-to-render-sharepoint-list-data-from-a-google-calendar.aspx). This displays SP calender in Google. It needs your site has basic authentication or Anonymous access enabled.