# How to synchronize Google Calender and SharePoint Calender ?

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, custom-web-parts

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I wants to create web part that synchronize My Google Calender and SharePoint Calender in both way **Google to SharePoint** and **SharePoint to Google**.
I need to create a web-part using c# code

can any body know how to do this ?

Reply as soon as possible

Comment: I think same question was asked before.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47838/sync-google-calendar-with-sharepoint-calendar

Answer (score 3):

Vikalp,

Many people have asked this question before:

[Sharepoint Calendar sync with Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382897/sharepoint-calendar-sync-with-google-calendar)
[How to syncroniz google calender with sharepoint 2007 calender](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminlegacy/thread/941f69bb-af9b-4b24-8fe0-eece93520426)
[Sync calendar between Sharepoint, Google, Outlook](http://kmlsp.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/sync-calendar-between-sharepoint-google-outlook/)

I hope this helps!